# In complex power and power factor analysis, how do I get the Thevenin impedance if there is a dependent source?

Tags: analysis, circuit-analysis

I'm preparing for my exam tomorrow, and I've found something ambiguous. How do I get the Thevenin impedance for this circuit?

Is it possible for me to get the impedance of the dependent source and then get the equivalent Thevenin impedance of the whole circuit? I have to find the equivalent resistance of the circuit because I need to add a power factor correcting reactance as seen from the terminals of the independent source.

Ia is already in RMS by the way since the given source is an RMS voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjT7HG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The given circuit is already in the phasor domain. We have to solve it there. By operating frequency, you mean the omega (w)? or (f)?

Comment: In general, you "connect" a test source to the terminals you're trying to find the Thevenin equivalent between, and find the current through/voltage across it to determine Zth.

Comment: @Shamtam My problem with that method is that I don't know how to do it without the removal of the device in question. There's practically no device in question in this circuit UNLESS I'm allowed to remove and replace the independent source with an open that will serve as the terminals for the test/excite source. Since I'm looking for the Thevenin impedance with respect to the independent source terminals, can this idea work?

Comment: Thevenin equivalent circuits rely on a perspective of _where_ you want the equivalent circuit. For instance, you'd get a different Thevenin equivalent across R1 than you would around C1 (in the given circuit).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question and the comments, I believe first of all some clarification is needed.

First of all you need to tell us **where** you intend to calculate the Thévenin equivalent: you can do that across any two terminals of that particular circuit since it is linear **and** the controlled voltage source control quantity is *inside* the circuit you want to reduce.

For example, if you want to calculate the Thévenin equivalent impedance of the net across the \$ V_{rms} \$ voltage source it would be zero since it is ideal.

To calculate the Thévenin equivalent impedance across any two other terminals you first need to turn off any independent voltage/current source, then connect a test source \$V_t\$ across the terminal you have chosen, solve the circuit, obtain the test current \$I_t\$ and finally compute \$Z_{th}=\frac{V_t}{I_p}\$.

I believe that what you want to do is calculate the Thévenin impedance seen from \$V_{rms}\$. To do that \$V_{rms}\$ must be removed, then usual circuit approach can be applied.

Let's call N the node where the resistor, the inductor and the capacitor are connected. From \$R_1\$ arrives a current \$I_t\$ that then splits in the two branches. Let's call \$I^*\$ the current that flows in \$L_1\$, and \$V_n\$ the voltage at node n. Let's finally tie the node \$V_{rms}\$, \$C_1\$, \$Vccs_1\$ to the ground. 
If \$Z_n\$ is the impedance seen across node n and ground removing \$R_1\$, you can write \$Z_{th} = R_1 + Z_n\$. Can we calculate \$Z_n\$ easily? **Yes.**

You can write:
$$
I^* = I_t - \frac{V^*}{Z_{C_1}}
$$
$$
I^* = \frac{V^*-\frac{I_t}{2}}{Z_{L_1}}
$$
From these you can derive:
$$
V^* = I_t\frac{1+\frac{1}{2Z_{L_1}}}{Z_{L_1}//Z_{C_1}}
$$
where \$Z_{L_1}//Z_{C_1} = \frac{Z_{L_1}Z_{C_1}}{Z_{L_1}+Z_{C_1}}\$

Now, \$Z_n = \frac{V_n}{I_t}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{2Z_{L_1}}}{Z_{L_1}//Z_{C_1}}\$, and finally:
$$
Z_{th} = R_1 + \frac{V_n}{I_t}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{2Z_{L_1}}}{Z_{L_1}//Z_{C_1}}=(1.9375-0.24j)\Omega
$$